# Convert data column to vector for plotting graph

Tags: r, database, statistics

I want to have a lollipop plot using data imported from Excel. My `data.strain1` is as follow

```r
data.strain1 <- structure(list(Discrimination_ratio = c(5.6, 2.4, 14.4, 10.8, 
3.5, 2.6, 1.7, 4.2, 4.6, 0.5, 2.6, 1.2, 3, 17.7, 4.4, -0.7, 9.3
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
data.strain1
#    Discrimination_ratio
# 1                   5.6
# 2                   2.4
# 3                  14.4
# 4                  10.8
# 5                   3.5
# 6                   2.6
# 7                   1.7
# 8                   4.2
# 9                   4.6
# 10                  0.5
# 11                  2.6
# 12                  1.2
# 13                  3.0
# 14                 17.7
# 15                  4.4
# 16                 -0.7
# 17                  9.3
```

```
toplot.strain1 <- data.frame(x=LETTERS[1:17],y=select(data.strain1,2))
ggplot(toplot.strain1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=x, yend=y)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'y' not found
```

I think the problem is that y is not recognized as vector in R. Tho I'm brand new to R, so please let me know what went wrong and how i can fix it.

Comment: is the comma in the discrimination ratio of your data a decimal place? Or are there two values in the same column?

Comment: It's a decimal place :)

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly. (I transcribed those numbers by-hand, please check in case I did it incorrectly. Also, you reference multiple columns in that data but only show one, so your `select(data.strain1,2)` won't work correctly.)

Comment: `select` is returning a full frame, not a vector (test it and see). Because of that, if you look at `toplot.strain1` you'll see that your attempted assignment to `y=` is ignored. Replace your reference to `y` (in your plot code) to `Discrimination_ratio` or rename it manually. Or replace `select(data.strain1,2)` with `data.strain1[[2]]`, which *will* be a vector.

Comment: To elaborate on what @r2evans said about getting a vector: (assuming the `select` you're using is from `dplyr`) take a look at the docs for `dplyr::select`: it returns an object of the same class as the object you feed it. So calling `select` on a data frame returns a data frame, not a vector.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.strain1$x <- LETTERS[1:nrow(data.strain1)]

ggplot(data.strain1, aes(x, Discrimination_ratio)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(aes(x=min(x),  y=min(Discrimination_ratio), xend=max(x), 
                yend=max(Discrimination_ratio)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @r2evans noted, the first issue was `select(DF, 2)` when the dataset only contained one column. Also, the `ggplot` call probably needs changed to make it more of a lollipop.

```
data.strain1$ID <- seq_len(nrow(data.strain1))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.strain1, aes(color = Discrimination_ratio > ID)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = LETTERS[ID], y = Discrimination_ratio))+
  geom_abline(slope = 1)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = LETTERS[ID], xend = LETTERS[ID]
                   , y = ID, yend = Discrimination_ratio))
```

[image]